# TILED 2D Tilemap is jumpy/jerky in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rendering

Using the application Tiled I made a 2D tilemap for a 2D Unity game I am making. The game is very simple, and the map consisted of only some regular tiles, and some with collision detectors. When I import the map into Unity to use for my game with Tiled2Unity, the game loads fine and everything works well, except every now and then the map skips like there is a rendering lag. The jump seems to be independent of the size of the tilemap, does anyone have any idea what the problem could be? I'm happy to answer any questions about the situation.

Here is a picture, you cannot see the problem because it's not a video but here is the situation at least:
[image]

Comment: Try splitting map into chunks instead of loading all at once.

Comment: @m.rogalski I think Tiled does that for you automatically